# Using @Index in Spring Data JPA entities in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In a Sprng Boot app where I use PostgreSQL as database, I am trying to use Hibernate and want to add indexes to an entity for the following situations:

**1.** There is not any account with the same userId and iban or with the same userId and name (unique index)

**2.** I want to make a commonly used query by iban field and wanted to add an index

Here is my implementation below:

```
@Entity
@Table(indexes = {
        @Index(name = "account_user_id_iban_key", columnList = "userId, iban", unique = true),
        @Index(name = "account_user_id_name_key", columnList = "userId, name", unique = true),
        @Index(name = "account_iban_idx", columnList = "iban")
})
public class Account {
    ...
}
```

My questions:

**1.** Is this implementation correct for the given scenario?

**2.** Do I need `@Index(name = "account_iban_idx", columnList = "iban")` index if I use `@NaturalId` for the `iban` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, implementation seems to be correct and if you frequently query by the iban field, it may be useful to have an additional index even if you're already using `@NaturalId` which is a way to define a natural identifier for your entity, but it does not automatically create an index on that field. Adding an additional index on the iban field will further optimize your queries.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I removed `@NaturalId` and make that iban field unique. For this reason, I think I do not need `@Index(name = "account_iban_idx", columnList = "iban")`, because making unique creates unique constraing / index and for this reason there is no need to also add an index for a unique field. Right?

Comment: @springer no, indexing means assing a unique id for every row so db will search of that field faster. unique fields (beside primary keys) also can have index.